# In Excel, finding if cell contains any character other than letters, a dot . , single quotation and space

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table, and would like to identify the cells (as HIT) that contain characters other than

- letters
- dot .
- single quotation

[image]

Which formula can I use for this? I've tried different functions, they don't seem to work.

Comment: What about a space then? You seem to have spaces but still want to return 'No Hit'?

Answer (score 2):

I think there will be a bunch of possibilities. Here is one using the logic that we will check every character in your string against all characters you'd like to exclude:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(SUM(--ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'. "))),"Hit","No Hit")
```

**Note**: I deliberately included a space since you seems to be wanting to exclude that too.

---

Other options could be:

```
=IF(REDUCE(LOWER(A2),MID("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.' ",SEQUENCE(29),1),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"")))<>"","Hit","No Hit")
```

Or with `FILTERXML()`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&LOWER(A2)&"</s></t>","//s[translate(., ""abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.' "", '')!='']")),"No Hit","Hit")
```

Though these options are more verbose and both `SUBSTITUTE()` and `FILTERXML()` are case-sensitive whereas `SEARCH()` is not.

Answer (score 0):

So, perhaps easier to do:

```
IF(MAX(IFERROR(FIND(".",A1,1),0),IFERROR(FIND("'",A1,1),0))>0,"No Hit","Hit")
```

[image]

I did not include a space but that is easily edited in.

Comment: What about letters?

Comment: @JvdV every cell there contains letters...

Comment: That's not the point. OP needs to know there are other characters than letters, dots and or single quotes. Hence the output for `Amsterdam` should be `No Hit`. There is no other character.